# Using loop to print out triangle

Tags: c, while-loop, variable-initialization

The task is to print the following shape using `while` loop only.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

The following code is what I have tried already, but it doesn't work unfortunately:

```
#include "stdafx.h"//Visual Studio 2015
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>// using for command system("pause") ;
#include <math.h>


    int main()
    {
        int i=0, k=0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            while (k <= i)
            {
                printf("*");
                k++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

I can't debug it by myself. Could anyone debug this one for me?

Comment: Move the declaration and initialization-to-zero of `k` *inside* the `while(i<10)` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must put `k=0` inside the loop, to make it go back to zero every loop.

```
    int main() {
        int i=0, k=0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            k=0; //<-- HERE
            while (k <= i)
            {
                printf("*");
                k++;
            }
            printf("\n");
            i++;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It only requires little correction

```
int i=0; 
    while (i < 10)
    {
    int k=0;
        while (k <= i)
        {
            printf("*");
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
```

[Working Example](http://ideone.com/BlkmNc)

Comment: Description of  your fix would have been bit more helpful for op